# dom structure movement with jquery

Tags: jquery, dom, select, click

I am creating a jquery script in which if a certain link element is clicked, the css of a following div changes. My problem is, that the next element is in a "parent dom tree" and I don't know how to select it.

If you take a look at my following html example you will know what mean.. ;)

```
<div class="box">
                        <div class="rentenBox"><a href="#" title="Info"><span class="hide">Info</span></a></div>
                        <div class="obereZeile"></div>
                        <div class="untereZeile"></div> 

</div> <!-- .box -->
<div class="blueButtonInfo"></div>
```

So, if the user clicks on .rentenBox a, the css of .blueButtonInfo should change.

Here is my jQuery so far:

```
$('.rentenBox a').click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $(this).next('.blueButtonInfo').css('display', 'none');

            })
```

I appreciate every help. Thx! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `blueButtonInfo` div is next to the `box` so you must go up 2 elements and then call next

```
$(this).parent().parent().next('.blueButtonInfo').css('display', 'none');

//or

$(this).parents('.box').next('.blueButtonInfo').css('display', 'none');
```

Comment: You only have to go up one element.

Comment: no you have to go up 2 because `$(this)` is refering to the `a`

Comment: both your solutions work. :) But I have one more problem. It works with .css('display', 'none') but when I want it to appear from a default css display:none; state with .css('display', 'visible'); it doesn't work.. Do you have any idea what the problem might be? Thank you.

Comment: Should be `css('display', 'block');`

Comment: Oh no, I am sorry. I mixed up. locrizak is right. The solutions of citizen conn don't.. But thank you anyway both! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).parent().next().css('display', 'none');
```

**or**

```
$(this).parent().siblings('.blueButtonInfo').css('display', 'none');
```

The first one will work if the div you are targeting is always after the current div's parent. The second one will always work if the div's class is `blueButtonInfo`.